I can't get a for loop with string variables to work
I'm trying to find the mean using a for loop from a dataframe structured like something below:
Month    Rate
Apr 22   112
Apr 22   117
Apr 22   45
Apr 23   110
Apr 23   130
Apr 23   34
Apr 24   115
Apr 24   128
Apr 24   40
Aug 22   27
Aug 22   101
Aug 22   27
Aug 23   112
Aug 23   61
Aug 23   68
etc.

The list goes on in alphabetical order spanning from 01/2024 to 07/2024. Since I wanted to find the mean for each month, I decided to use a for loop but my code below doesn't work. I'm a beginner in R (and stack overflow) and could use some help, thanks! If a for loop isn't the best function to use, I'd appreciate the insight as well. bind_long1 is the dataframe name.
datelist <- c("Jan 22", "Feb 22", "Mar 22", "Apr 22", "May 22", "Jun 22", "Jul 22", "Aug 22", "Sep 22", "Oct 22", "Nov 22", "Dec 22", "Jan 23", "Feb 23", "Mar 23", "Apr 23", "May 23", "Jun 23", "Jul 23", "Aug 23", "Sep 23", "Oct 23", "Nov 23", "Dec 23", "Jan 24", "Feb 24", "Mar 24", "Apr 24", "May 24", "Jun 24", "Jul 24")

for (i in datelist) {
    mean(bind_long1[bind_long1$Month == i,2])
}

I want the output to be a dataframe that looks something like this:
Month    Avg Rate
Apr 22   91.33333
Apr 23   91.33333
Apr 24   44.33333
Aug 22   51.66667
Aug 23   80.33333
etc.


bind_long1 |> dplyr::summarize(Avg_Rate = mean(Rate), .by = Month) or aggregate(Rate ~ Month, data = bind_long1, mean)
